# How to prevent two Collections

Tags: collections

I have created a model consisting of a number of mesh cube objects (resized etc) and have ONE collection containing each of the cube objects.
When I import an FBX object Blender places it into a new collection and I wonder if that is because it is an import rather than a new mesh object.
I read that a collection is a set of objects you define as being related to each other in some way and the imported fbx is related to everything else.
Does it matter that I end up with 2 collections? When I export my model as an extended gLtf file (for MSFS2020) two .xml file are created and while that doesn't matter I guess I just wonder if I can prevent 2 collections?

Answer (score 3):

Oops it seems that I needed to hightlite the original collection before importing the fbx object. I don't know what in the past created a new (empty) collection.